# Ruby/rails: mongoid with mongo(gem); a bson conflict? How to handle different versions?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, mongoid

How to handle gem version mis-matches?

Mongoid 4.0.0 (latest) uses moped (2.0.0) which requires bson 2.3

Mongo 1.10.2 (latest) uses bson 1.10.2

I can't use mongoid 4.0.0 and mongo 1.10.2 together, but I could in the past, when mongoid uses bson 1.x.

Does anyone know how I can continue forward using both mongo and mongoid?

-daniel

Links:

- https://rubygems.org/gems/mongoid
- https://rubygems.org/gems/moped
- https://rubygems.org/gems/mongo

Comment: Can you drop mongo and use moped instead?

Comment: @muistooshort humm, a solution; I definately need mongoid a whole lot more than I need mongo(gem); so I guess I can :)

Comment: mongo(gem) 2.x has bson 2.x as a requirement: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/mongo.gemspec

Comment: Drop the mongo gem completely and just use Moped. That's what I did when I switch to Mongoid and I've been a lot happier with Moped than I ever was with the mongo gem.

Comment: @Daniel this is on master, for the yet unreleased 2.0 version of the gem, as of aug 2014  , 1.10.x is still conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

The latest unstable version 2.x (under heavy development) of mongo-ruby-driver uses BSON 2.2.  If you upgrade to this Gem you should be good to go.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/mongo.gemspec