# How do I batch insert documents into MongoDB and only reject duplicates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

From my Ruby on Rails application I need to insert `Customer` documents into **MongoDB**. For performance reasons I need to batch insert them:

```
Customer.collection.insert([{mail_address: "hello_1@hello_1.com"}, {mail_address: "hello_2@hello_2.com"}])
```

I have an index to enforce uniqueness of the `mail_address` attribute:

```
index({ mail_address: 1 },  { background: true, unique: true })
```

But this means that if one fails, the entire batch fails.

**How do I batch insert documents, and only fail/reject the duplicate documents?**

Answer (score 0):

If you use an [Unordered Bulk Write Operation](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/wiki/Bulk-Write-Operations#unordered-bulk-write-operation), the entire batch will be attempted and an error report will be returned.

This is using the [Mongo Ruby Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver) directly. I do not think that Mongoid supports this api directly. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550690/mongoid-batch-update-upsert-alternative) describes a solution using Mongoid.

Comment: It seems that I can't use the `mongo` gem and the `mongoid` gem at the same time according the [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395147/ruby-rails-mongoid-with-mongogem-a-bson-conflict-how-to-handle-different-ve). The post suggest to use `moped` instead. Can the same operation be performed with `moped`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding records in bulk, with a unique index, and even though the operation fails, I still observe the new records being created (i.e. it fails only on duplicates, not the entire bulk operation).

```
  batch = []
    chatters.each do |chatter|
      today = Time.now.to_date
      batch.push({ :influencer_name_downcase => channel_name, :name => chatter, :date_seen => today })
    end

    begin
      a = Kuv.collection.insert_many( batch )
    rescue Mongo::Error::BulkWriteError => e
      ;
    end
```